# zpl graphics not always printing

Tags: printing, graphic, zpl

I have a ZPL label which prints successfully when printed individually, but when printing a number of labels in quick succession the occasional one does not print the graphics part only.

The graphics are downloaded, recalled and deleted using the following ZPL commands.

```
^XA^CFD^PW584^FS
^PON^FS
~DGR:IMG1.GRF,15042,23,....
^FO250,770^XGR:IMG1.GRF,1,1^FS
^IDR:IMG1.GRF^FS
^XZ
```

I've tried giving every file a unique graphics name rather than IMG1, but still occasional label with no graphics printed. 
Any ideas?